# Setting up 3d Collision for Primitive shapes

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection, bounding-boxes

Im having some trouble understanding how to set up collision detection between my first person camera and my primitive shapes which are made using the vertex buffer. Do i give my camera a boundingBox and all my objects a boundingbox then add them to a list and check the list for collsions or is there a better more understanding way to do this. My game is literally a maze game so all i really need is my camera to accept collisions against the primitive objects. Thanks in advance.